# Использование HTTPS прокси для GET запроса к HTTPS сайту C#

Tags: c#, https, proxy

Есть ли какие то библиотеки или костыли, с помощью которых возможно организовать запросы через **HTTPS** прокси?

Код **работает для HTTP прокси** и не работает для ssl прокси:
[image: Прокси]

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com") as HttpWebRequest;
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("188.166.210.210:8080");

using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
      Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

```
//xNet
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
   request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
   request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse("159.89.24.212:8080");

   HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://twitter.com");
   Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, который не работает, желательно конкретный пример. Прокся с авторизацией? Прокся поддерживает HTTPS? А так - [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605900/12888024).

Comment: @aepot добавил пример кода и переформулировал более точно вопрос

Comment: `188.166.210.210:8080` и `159.89.24.212:8080` видно же по скриншоту, что они не поддерживают SSL.

Comment: @aepot я же написал, что с ними как раз таки и работает, можете сами запустить код, а вот прокси запросы к которым шифруются ssl, не поддерживается

Comment: Ну, и в чем проблема тогда? (кроме того что вы используете устаревший `WebRequest`). Если URL сайта у вас HTTPS, значит и запрос идет HTTPS.

Comment: @aepot проблема: WebRequest и xNet не поддерживают HTTPS прокси, а хотелось бы чтоб работало, какие есть альтернативные актуальные библиотеки которые поддерживают?

Comment: Не путайте HTTPS прокси и HTTPS запрос к целевому серверу. HTTPS запрос к целевому серверу может пройти спокойно через HTTP прокси. И при этом Роскомнадзор даже его пропустит.

Comment: @aepot, Кажется вы меня не поняли, мне как раз таки и нужно использование HTTPS прокси, а через HTTP прокси все замечательно работает

Comment: [Окей](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18682942/12888024), а зачем? Если кратко, то .NET не поддерживает "из коробки" SSL-прокси, потому что это как бы даже и не особо стандарт и не популярная тема. Да и бессмысленное это занятие еще раз шифровать уже шифрованное соединение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается использованием библиотеки [Chilkat.Http](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/)

```
// This example requires the Chilkat API to have been previously unlocked.
// See Global Unlock Sample for sample code.

Chilkat.Http http = new Chilkat.Http();

// Set the HTTP proxy domain or IP address.
http.ProxyDomain = "172.16.16.46";
// The proxy port..
http.ProxyPort = 3128;

// Indicate that we are to use a direct TLS connection with the HTTP proxy
// (we use a Squid Cache: Version 4.11 for testing)
http.ProxyDirectTls = true;

// If the proxy requires a login or password, we can set it here.
// Otherwise comment out these lines.
http.ProxyLogin = "myProxyLogin";
http.ProxyPassword = "myProxyPassword";

// All requests sent on the http object will now go through the proxy.
// Give it a test:
string s = http.QuickGetStr("https://www.chilkatsoft.com/helloWorld.html");
if (http.LastMethodSuccess == false) {
    Console.WriteLine(http.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

// The LastErrorText property also contains information when method call succeeds.
// Have a look to see that the request was sent through the proxy:
Console.WriteLine(http.LastErrorText);

Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine("Success for TLS destination over direct TLS HTTP proxy.");
```

[Подробнее...](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/squid_direct_tls_connection.asp)